# Qt - CustomContextMenu remains open after selecting an option

Tags: qt

I have a CustomContextMenu that open whens I right click on an item in a QTableWidget. The menu works fine, however, if I click one of the options the menu stays open, if I click the same option again it performs the action again and the menu closes. This only happens with one of the options.

I've not really got any idea why this happens and can't find anything online as to why this happens. If anyone has any idea what could be causing it to stay open it would be greatly appreciated.

```
QAction *newGroupAction = new QAction("Raise New", this);
QAction *deleteGroupAction = new QAction("Delete", this);

connect(newGroupAction, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)),this, SLOT(newItem()));
connect(deleteGroupAction, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)),this, SLOT(deleteItem()));

menu = new QMenu(this);
menu->addAction(newGroupAction);
if(ui->table->selectedItems().size() > 0 && adminPrivilege == true)
{
    menu->addAction(deleteGroupAction);
}
menu->popup(ui->table->horizontalHeader()->viewport()->mapToGlobal(pos));


void TableWidget::deleteItem()
{
    int ID = ui->table->item(ui->table->currentIndex().row(), 0)->text().toInt();

    if(adminPrivilege == true)
    {
         QSqlQuery query;
         query.prepare("DELETE FROM NOTES WHERE ID = (:id)");
         query.bindValue(":id", ID);
         query.exec();

         QSqlQuery query2;
         query2.prepare("DELETE FROM PAGES WHERE ID = (:id)");
         query2.bindValue(":id", ID);
         query2.exec();
    }
    else
    {
         QMessageBox error;
         error.setWindowTitle("Error!");
         error.setText("You do not have the correct privilege to delete");
         error.exec();
    }
    load();
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code ?

Comment: @ThibautB. Sure. I've added it to the question

Comment: This part of code is in a ```public slots``` ? So you create a new ```QMenu``` on each right clic ? gives more details please.

Comment: It's in a private slot and yes it does create a new QMenu on every right click. Sorry about the lack of information, all of my code is on a PC that is unable to connect to the internet so I have to rewrite it all to show you it.

Comment: So you never delete the ```QMenu``` after popup. With just this part of code I can't help you more, but if you have just one ```QMenu``` with your actions it will be better. Give more information when you can.

Comment: You can take a look to this page : [Menus Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-menus-example.html)

Comment: Yeah I've changed the code to declare my menu in the header. I'll add the code to the function that the menu doesn't close on.

Comment: Does the problem also occur if you use a queued connection (passing `Qt::QueuedConnection` in the `connect` call)?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to change anything. It's occurred to me that I may need to explain this issue in more depth so I'll add to my explanation.

Comment: I can't currently edit my post so I'll just add the detail in the comments

Comment: To me it seems like the issue comes from the menu itself rather than the actions included in it. I'm going to try my best to describe what I see when it occurs. The two options I have in my menu are: creating a new group and deleting a group. The new group action opens a widget in a new window, it could be that the issue would occur if it wasn't for the fact a new window opens with that action.

Comment: The delete action however, just deletes a group from the table and the database, this doesn't open a new window and instead the menu stays open. When I click the delete option, it carries out the function fine but the menu remains open. The option loses its blue highlight as if the mouse wasn't hovering over it. I am able to select either of the options again and they both function properly, however, this time I can click both options to cause the menu to close.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I have also just noticed that the issue occurs if I click away from the menu. For example if I were to right click and then move my mouse off of the menu and left click the menu will stay open until I click again.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the content of deleteItem? So nothing happens when you choose that option?

Comment: The menu remains open no matter what I have in the menu. I've just made a context menu in another program with pretty much the same code and it works correctly.